# Hierarchical data searching

Tags: ms-access

I have a table CATEGORY, where I have categories. Each category may have subcategories (or childs). If it is a main category parent = 0, otherwise it equals the parent id. For example,

```
   ID |Category  |Parent
   1   Fruit      0
   2   Apple      1
   3   Orange     1
   4   Vegetable  0
   5   Onion      4
   6   Tomato     4
   7   Red Apple  2
   8   Green Apl  2
```

So using code I am able to create the following list

```
Fruit
  - Apple
    - Red Apple
    - Green Apl
  - Orange
Vegetable
  - Onion
  - Tomato
```

I have other table SOLD_ITEMS where I use CATEGORY.ID.

## Questions

**1)** Could someone help me to perform a query FROM SOLD_ITEMS WHERE CATEGORY.ID equals Fruits or any of it childs?

I may be able to code it outside SQL and generate a query string like: WHERE CATEGORY.ID IN (1,2,3,4,7,8), I am just wondering if there is an alternative to do it in a SQL statement

**2)** Using SQL, is there a query where I can get the upper most parent given a CATEGORY.ID? e.g. For 8 (Green Apl) will be 1. For 4 (Vegetable) will be 4.

I may be complicating the thing using SQL, I may not. I am not so profficient using SQL yet.

Comment: Your question tagged with three different DBMS. Possible solution depends on exact DBMS you're using.

Comment: Sorry Andy Korneyev , I am using VB.net and MS-Access database

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading and implementing the Nested Set model for hierarchies in databases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about nested set model, although the queries will be simplified it adds complexity to INSERT, UPDATE, change parent, etc. I would have to ensure that every change in the Category_ID gets reflected in the current records linked to Category_ID.

So, I decided to use VB.net TreeView1. It may not be the best answer, but it is simple to implement

```
Sub Load_Cateogries(treeview1 As TreeView)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sSQL As String

    treeview1.Nodes.Clear()

    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Product_Categories WHERE Parent=0"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    If Query_DB(cmd, ds) Then
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            Dim TNode As TreeNode

            TNode = treeview1.Nodes.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Category").ToString)
            TNode.Tag = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Category_ID").ToString

            Load_Category(TNode.Tag, TNode)
        Next
    End If

    treeview1.ExpandAll()
End Sub

Sub Load_Category(iParent As Integer, tn As TreeNode)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sSQL As String

    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Product_Categories WHERE Parent=" & iParent
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    If Query_DB(cmd, ds) Then
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            Dim TNode As TreeNode

            TNode = tn.Nodes.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Category").ToString)
            TNode.Tag = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Category_ID").ToString

            Load_Category(TNode.Tag, TNode)
        Next
    End If

    ds.Dispose()
End Sub
```

And the query for a Category and its childs can be completed as 
`"SELECT * FROM Product_Categories WHERE Category_ID IN (" & Get_Parent_and_Childs() & ")"` for a selectednode in this case, letting the control to sort it out (function TreeView1.Nodes.Find() becomes useful if you want a specific Parent without letting the user to select it).

```
Function Get_Parent_and_Childs() As String
    Dim sTag As String = ""

    If TreeView1.SelectedNode IsNot Nothing Then
        sTag = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Tag
        Get_Child(sTag, TreeView1.SelectedNode)
    End If

    Return sTag
End Function

Sub Get_Child(ByRef sTag As String, nParent As TreeNode)
    For Each n As TreeNode In nParent.Nodes
        sTag &= ", " & n.Tag
        Get_Child(sTag, sDesc, n)
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!